# How to resize this ubuntu partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, resize

I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7. My Ubuntu partition (/sda7) is filling up and thus I want to increase the size of that partition.

Can someone please explain how do I do this without formatting my harddisk as reinstalling all the software and stuff would be really painful?

[image]

Comment: What is sda5 partition? Is it needed?

Comment: it contains my old wubi partition which is not needed anymore.

Comment: I think it is better to uninstall wubi from Windows first. Not just remove the partition.

Comment: hmm yeah. i'll give it a shot.  i'm in the process of backing up some files, will update here how it goes. hopefully well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to boot from Ubuntu LiveUSB and start gparted there.

I see that you have 19.53 unallocated space. You can use it to extend sda7.

1. Move left side of **sda4** left.
2. Move left **sda5**, or remove it, if you do not need this "New Volume".
3. Now you can extend **sda7** left.

***Do not forget to press "Apply" button in gparted***

After you move the Ubuntu boot partiton you will have to restore-grub.

It can be done this way from LiveUSB.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo update-grub
exit
```

Comment: sda5 needs to be defragged before doing this as per gparted's instructions. Otherwise it can fail and take ages to finish the task. 2ndly: remove sda5? Why your even suggest removing a partition that holds 30+ GB of data is beyond me. Bad advice.

Comment: @Rinzwind I suspect sda5 was created in attempts to do something. Let's wait for OPs answer. And also defrag is not a must if you just move a partition.

Comment: @Rinzwind  You wrote an answer that would have lead to unbootable system, then removed it and downvoted the correct one. Great!

Comment: thanks for the ans. I'm in the process of doing this. yes @Pilot6 is right, sda5 contains wubi which i'm not using anymore so i should be able to remove it without any hassle.

Comment: @Rinzwind It is clearly mentioned that *if you do not need*, so I would not take it as a bad advice.

Comment: i lost my bootmenu after removing the wubi partition. Now I have got it back after using the boot-repair tool (but doesn't have the windows boot menu there now :( ).

Comment: and also as you suggested 'Move left side of sda4 left.'. I'm unable to do it inside GParted..I can move sda7 to left since i dont have sda5, but how do i make use of the unallocated 19.53GB space? thanks

Comment: @KillBill You probably need to disable swap.